# Nearest Neighbor Searching using Voronoi Diagrams

Tags: computational-geometry, nearest-neighbor, voronoi

I've successfully implemented a way to generate Voronoi diagrams in 2 dimensions using Fortune's method.  But now I'm trying to use it for nearest neighbor queries for a point (which is not one of the original points used to generate the diagram).  I keep seeing people saying that it can be done in O(lg n) time (and I believe them), but I can't find a description of how it's actually done.

I'm familiar with binary searches, but I can't figure out a good criteria to guarantee that upper bound.  I also figured maybe it could have to do with inserting the point into the diagram and updating surrounding cells, but can't think (or find) of a good way to do that.

Can anyone clue me in, or point to a place with a more thorough description?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that some kind of search structure has to be made from plane subdivision (Voronoi diagram), like [Kirkpatrick's point location data structure](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2002/PaulSandulescu/).

Comment: That makes sense.  I think I'm familiar with that method.  I'd upvote you, but I can't yet.

Comment: @Chad: I haven't been familiar with Kirkpatrick structure until I searched because of your question:-) I worked with Voronoi diagrams before, but I never used them for point location. This method looks quite nice.