# Efficient algorithm for finding closest point in a finite set to another point

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a list L of ~30k locations (written as longitude/latitude pairs), and a list E of ~1m events (with locations written as longitude/latitude pairs), each of which occurs at a point in L. I want to tag each event in E with its corresponding location in L. But the cooordinates in L and E are rounded differently—E to five decimal places, L to thirteen—so ostensibly identical coordinates can actually differ by ~10^-5 degrees, or ~1 meter. (Points in L are separated by at least ~10 m.)

I thus need the nearest point in L to every point of E; the obvious O(|L||E|) brute-force algorithm is too slow. L is small enough compared to E that algorithms that preprocess L and amortize the preprocessing time over E are fine. Is this a well-studied problem? The links that I can find are for related but distinct problems, like finding the minimal distance between a pair of points in one set.

Possibly relevant: [Voronoi diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram), though I can't see how preprocessing L into a Voronoi diagram would save me computational time.

Comment: Ok.. I've skipped most of your post because there's just too much useless information. Basically, you have a list 'L' of 30k XY points (call that lat/long if you want), and you have a list 'E' of a million XY points (ditto), and you want to know for each point in E which one in 'L' it's closest to. Is that it ? Please confirm.

Comment: Wait - if the rounding errors cause a deviation of up to 1m, but the minimal distance between points is 10m, then you can just round both to the same precision and compare equality, right?

Comment: @AlexG: can confirm (and I've redacted some of the useless information).

Comment: @ConnorHarris thanks. Looks like a Quadtree should do the job. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree There are probably a bunch of open source libraries that implements it, but I think you could do it yourself quite easily. Sort all your reference points by x. Sort the first half and the second half by y. You've just split your points into 4 regions. Just do that recursively while building a tree structure until each region contains only 1 point. After that, you can search for the closest point by comparing the ranges and traversing the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct. First you can construct the Voronoi Diagram of your point set of locations L in O(|L| log |L|) time using [Furtune's Sweep Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm) approach. There are various implementations out there that can be used, [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) would be among the most common ones.

Now you have a partitioning of the plane of O(|L|) size. To allow O(log |L|) nearest neighbour queries you need a search structure on top of the Voronoi diagram. A common approach is to use the Dobkin-Kirkpatrick Hierarchy, details can be found in various [lecture notes](https://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/~held/teaching/compgeo/cg_print.pdf). This method supports O(log |L|) queries and also requires only O(|L|) size. (Also mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113668/nearest-neighbor-searching-using-voronoi-diagrams).)

Then the |E| queries can be accomplished in O(|E| log |L|) time.

A different approach would be to use [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). From an implementation point of view they might be less work and provide the same complexities (as far as iI know).
A quick search revealed these two implementations that are maybe worth testing: [C++](https://github.com/gvd/kdtree), [Java](https://github.com/kostyaev/2D-Tree).

Comment: Voronoi + partitioning is in theory the best approach for real points. In practice it is a big and complex machinery for which special cases are a pain to handle. In practice I would also recommend a 2D-tree, far easier to implement.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, that is why I mentioned the trees in the end. Nevertheless, it is nice to know how the Voronoi Diagrams can be used in that matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is amenable to a fairly direct application of [space-partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Space_partitioning). Most GIS libraries should provide tools to do this.

My own experience is restricted to using [R-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).  I create an index of the L items. You can use the points directly or a bounding box representing the uncertainty around the point.  Then the R-tree supports an efficient (log(L) time) query of the n nearest neighbouring points/bounding boxes.

The implementation I have used successfully is [libspatialindex](http://libspatialindex.github.io/) wrapped into a python library called [Rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/).

However, note that this specific tool is accurate only when using Euclidean x,y coordinates. It has significant potential for error using lat longs away from the equator, and particularly if you want to cover a geographically large area. In my case I was restricted to a single country within which I used eastings/northings.  I'm not aware of which libraries provide support for handling the problem using great circle distances but they certainly ought to be available.

Answer (score 1):

From your description:

- Each point in E is identical to a point in L rounded to five decimal places. Thus, each point in E deviates up to ~1 meter from its match in L.
- Points in L are separated by at least ~10 meter.

**Solution:** Round coordinates in L to the same precision of E and match equal pairs.

**Explanation:** Rounding effectively maps each point to its nearest neighbor on a square grid. As long as the grid resolution (~1 meter when rounding to five decimals) is lower than half the minimal distance between two points in L (~10/2 meters), you are good to go.

For maximum performance and exploiting |L| << |E|, you might want to build a hash map over the rounded coordinates in L and match each point in E in near constant time. Total runtime would then be limited by O(|E|).

Comment: Interesting approach. There is a danger though that the values rounded with different policies will differ by one unit in some cases. In case of a miss, the neighboring bins will have to be tried as well.

Answer (score 0):

My library [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io) contains a class [NearestNeighbor](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/nearest.html)
which implements the [vantage-point trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantage-point_tree).  This works for any data
where there's a true distance metric; the geodesic distance obviously
satisfies this criterion.
Basically you initialize the class with your `L` locations 
and then for each of `E` events you
ask for the nearest location.  The breakdown on the computational
costs is as follows

```
set-up cost: L log L
cost per query: log L
cost of all queries: E log L
total cost: (L + E) log L
```

(These are base-2 logs.)  Here's code that will do the lookup.  Running this on 30k locations and 1M events takes about 40 secs and involved a total of 16M geodesic distance calculations.  (The brute force way would take about 21 hours.)

```
// Read lat/lon locations from locations.txt and lat/lon events from
// events.txt.  For each event print to closest.txt: the index for the
// closest location and the distance to it.

// Needs GeographicLib 1.47 or later

// compile and link with
// g++ -o closest closest.cpp -lGeographic \
//   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <GeographicLib/NearestNeighbor.hpp>
#include <GeographicLib/Geodesic.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace GeographicLib;

// A structure to hold a geographic coordinate.
struct pos {
  double lat, lon;
  pos(double lat = 0, double lon = 0)
    : lat(lat), lon(lon) {}
};

// A class to compute the distance between 2 positions.
class DistanceCalculator {
private:
  Geodesic _geod;
public:
  explicit DistanceCalculator(const Geodesic& geod)
    : _geod(geod) {}
  double operator() (const pos& a, const pos& b) const {
    double s12;
    _geod.Inverse(a.lat, a.lon, b.lat, b.lon, s12);
    return s12;
  }
};

int main() {
  // Define a distance function object
  DistanceCalculator distance(Geodesic::WGS84());

  // Read in locations
  vector<pos> locs;
  {
    double lat, lon;
    ifstream is("locations.txt");
    while (is >> lat >> lon)
      locs.push_back(pos(lat, lon));
  }

  // Construct NearestNeighbor object
  NearestNeighbor<double, pos, DistanceCalculator>
    locationset(locs, distance);

  ifstream is("events.txt");
  ofstream os("closest.txt");

  double lat, lon, d;
  vector<int> k;
  while (is >> lat >> lon) {
    pos event(lat, lon);
    d = locationset.Search(locs, distance, event, k);
    os << k[0] << " " << d << "\n";
  }
}
```