# STL: sorting and searching in enormous data

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, computational-geometry, point-clouds

I've two sets of points(`source` and `target`). The goal is to find, for each `source` point, an **unique 1:1 nearest neighbor** point in `target`.

My attempt is working as expected but ridiculously slow. I've tested on few thousand points but in actual scenario points would be millions. I'm no expert in **STL**. Any suggestion how I can optimize it?

```
std::vector<UT_Vector3> targetPosVector;
for (auto i = 0; i < targetNumPoints; i++)
{
    auto pos = target->getPos3(i);

    targetPosVector.push_back(pos);
}

std::vector<int> uniqueNeighborVector;
for (auto ptoff = 0; ptoff < sourceNumPoints; ptoff++)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, fpreal>> nearpointVector; // neighbor vector in form of "(idx, dist)"

    auto pos = source->getPos3(ptoff);
    for (auto j = 0; j < targetNumPoints; j++)
    {
        fpreal dist = pos.distance(targetPosVector[j]);

        std::pair<int, fpreal> neighbor {j, dist};
        nearpointVector.push_back(neighbor);
    }
    std::sort(nearpointVector.begin(), nearpointVector.end(), [](const std::pair<int, fpreal> &left,
                                                                 const std::pair<int, fpreal> &right)
                                                                { return left.second < right.second; });

    std::vector<int> neighborVector;
    for (auto i : nearpointVector)
    {
        neighborVector.push_back(i.first);
    }

    // trying to imitate Python's next() function
    // uniqueNeighborList[]
    // uneighbor = next(i for i in neighborVector if i not in uniqueNeighborVector)
    // uniqueNeighborVector = set(uniqueNeighborList.append(uneighbor))
    for (auto i : neighborVector)
    {     
        if (std::find(uniqueNeighborVector.begin(), uniqueNeighborVector.end(), i) == uniqueNeighborVector.end())
        {
            int uneighbor = i; // later on binds to the geometry attribute

            uniqueNeighborVector.push_back(i);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**where**:

- `source` and `target` are **Detail Geometry** data
- `distance` is a function to calculate distance between two vectors
- `getPos3` is a function to get `3-float vector` points position
- `fpreal` aka `64-bit float`
- `UT_Vector3` is `3-float vector`
- `sourceNumPoints` and `targetNumPoints` are number of points in
  `source` and `target` geometry respectively.

Comment: The standard library is really not optimized for this task. Have a look at specialized libraries, like [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/).

Comment: The issue here is not so much the STL as the algorithm chosen. You are generating a quadratic number of distance pairs, and so this approach won't scale into the millions of points. You will need to use some form of spatial subdivision to quickly reject impossible pairings instead of blindly trying all combinations.

Comment: Even so even the present brute-force implementation appears needlessly convoluted. I gather that a target point may only be matched once, with lower-ordered sources getting first dibs. If so then instead of the generating and sorting a temporary vector, then linearly scanning the full target set, I would propose dropping used targets (by swap-to-back) and selecting the best match in-line without the intermediate buffering and sorting. Granted it won't get you into the millions but it may be a start.

Comment: Target points are randomly scattered. Let's assume 1st point's nearest neighbor is 1203 and for 2nd point it could be anything like 719123 or something with huge jump.

Comment: @Pradeep Barua: Excellent, a (uniform) random distribution should make things relatively easy to handle. For instance you might try partitioning the target points into a 3D grid structure. Then during the search the directly index the nearest grid entry and gradually scan outwards, returning and removing the the first point found. With a grid size tuned to the density I believe that this should be roughly linear.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments a quadratic complexity is a downfall when attempting to compute this for millions of points. Even if you optimise your code, the quadratic complexity will stay if the approach does not change.

It sounds to me like a classical NN-Problem in R3. A well known approach is to use [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search), they allow for O(log n) query time within O(n log n) construction time and linear space. Implementations can be sought though various libraries: [nanoflann](https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann), [kdtree](https://github.com/orangejulius/kdtree) (These are from a quick search, I am certain there are also elaborate libraries containing k-d trees.)

Short recap: I would use a 3-d tree and build it on your target point set. Then take each of the source points (one by one) and find the nearest neighbour in the 3-d tree in O(log n) time each which will result in O(|source| log |target|) time and O(|target|) size.

A related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372780/efficient-algorithm-for-finding-closest-point-in-a-finite-set-to-another-point/43373912#43373912).