# Divide a region into parts efficiently Python

Tags: python, algorithm, computer-vision, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a square grid with some points marked off as being the centers of the subparts of the grid.  I'd like to be able to assign each location within the grid to the correct subpart.  For example, if the subparts of the region were centered on the black dots, I'd like to be able to assign the red dot to the region in the lower right, as it is the closest black dot.

[image]

Currently, I do this by iterating over each possible red dot, and comparing its distance to each of the black dots.  However, the width, length, and number of black dots in the grid is very high, so I'd like to know if there's a more efficient algorithm.

My particular data is formatted as such, where the numbers are just placeholders to correspond with the given example:

```
black_dots = [(38, 8), (42, 39), (5, 14), (6, 49)]
grid = [[0 for i in range(0, 50)] for j in range(0, 50)]
```

For reference, in the sample case, I hope to be able to fill `grid` up with integers 1, 2, 3, 4, depending on whether they are closest to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, or 4th entry in black_dots to end up with something that would allow me to create something similar to the following picture where each integer correspond to a color (dots are left on for show).

[image]

To summarize, is there / what is the more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How about BFS starting simultaneously from each point?

Comment: What you are looking for is called the Voronoi diagram of the centers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a breadth-first traversal to solve this problem.

1. Create a first-in, first-out queue. (A queue makes a traversal breadth-first.)
2. Create a Visited mask indicating whether a cell in your grid has been added to the queue or not. Set the mask to false.
3. Create a Parent mask indicating what black dot the cell ultimately belongs to.
4. Place all the black dots into the queue, flag them in the Visited mask, and assign them unique ids in the Parent mask.
5. Begin popping cells from the queue one by one. For each cell, iterate of the cell's neighbours. Place each neighbour into the Queue, flag it in Visited, and set its value in Parent to be equal to that of the cell you just popped.
6. Continue until the queue is empty.

The breadth-first traversal makes a wave which expands outward from each source cell (black dot). Since the waves all travel at the same speed across your grid, each wave gobbles up those cells closest to its source.

This solves the problem in *O(N)* time.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you really need is to construct a Voronoi diagram of your centers:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Which can be constructed very efficiently with similar computational complexity as calculating its convex hull.

The Voronoi diagram allows you to construct the optimal polygons sorrounding your centers which delimit the regions closest to the centers.

Having the Voronoi diagram the task is reduced to detect in which polygon the red dots lies. Since the Voronoi cells are convex you need an algorithm to decide wether a point is inside a convex polygon. However traversing all polygons has complexity O(n).

There are several algorithms to accelerate the point location so it can be done in O(log n):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location

See also

[Nearest Neighbor Searching using Voronoi Diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113668/nearest-neighbor-searching-using-voronoi-diagrams)

Comment: This approach is not the best idea. The Voronoi diagram computation is indeed very fast, unless the number of centers is large (it could even be of order N where N is the number  of pixels). But the transformation from the Voronoi cell to an efficient point location structure is not so cool, and the total workload for filling the map would be N Log(K) for K centers. A much better option is to fill every Voronoi cell with a scanline algorithm, which can be done in time O(A) where A is the polygon area (plus small overhead depending on the number of sides), for a total of O(N + K Log K).

Answer (score 1):

The "8-way" Voronoi diagram can be constructed efficiently (in linear time wrt the number of pixels) by a two-passes scanline process. (8-way means that distances are evaluated as the length of the shortest 8-connected path between two pixels.)

Assign every center a distinct color and create an array of distances of the same size as the image, initialized with 0 at the centers and "infinity" elsewhere.

In a top-down/left-right pass, update the distances of all pixels as being the minimum of the distances of the four neighbors W, NW, N and NE plus one, and assign the current pixel the color of the neighbor that achieves the minimum.

In a bottom-up/right-left pass, update the distances of all pixels as being the minimum of the current distance and the distances of the four neighbors E, SE, S, SW plus one, and assign the current pixel the color of the neighbor that achieves the minimum (or keep the current color).

---

It is also possible to compute the *Euclidean* Voronoi diagram efficiently (in linear time), but this requires a more sophisticated algorithm. It can be based on the wonderful paper "A GENERAL ALGORITHM FOR COMPUTING DISTANCE
TRANSFORMS IN LINEAR TIME" by A. MEIJSTER‚ J.B.T.M. ROERDINK and W.H. HESSELINK, which must be enhanced with some accounting of the neighbor that causes the smallest distance.