# Running time of finding nearest neighbour using d3 voronoi

Tags: algorithm, d3.js, nearest-neighbor, voronoi

What is the running time complexity of `d3.voronoi.find` method?

Here, https://visionscarto.net/the-state-of-d3-voronoi, it is written that it's raw speed is O(sqrt(n)), but what is the proof for that?

Also, is there any method for finding the nearest neighbour just by using the computed voronoi diagram in O(logn) time?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see, the [following code](https://github.com/Fil/d3-geo-voronoi) is `find` function which is talked about it:

```
find: function(x, y, radius) {
    var that = this, i0, i1 = that._found || 0, n = that.cells.length, cell;

    // Use the previously-found cell, or start with an arbitrary one.
    while (!(cell = that.cells[i1])) if (++i1 >= n) return null;
    var dx = x - cell.site[0], dy = y - cell.site[1], d2 = dx * dx + dy * dy;

    // Traverse the half-edges to find a closer cell, if any.
    do {
      cell = that.cells[i0 = i1], i1 = null;
      cell.halfedges.forEach(function(e) {
        var edge = that.edges[e], v = edge.left;
        if ((v === cell.site || !v) && !(v = edge.right)) return;
        var vx = x - v[0], vy = y - v[1], v2 = vx * vx + vy * vy;
        if (v2 < d2) d2 = v2, i1 = v.index;
      });
    } while (i1 !== null);

    that._found = i0;

    return radius == null || d2 <= radius * radius ? cell.site : null;
}
```

It depends on the specified radius to search over data point. Any how, as you can see it iterates over all half-edges (Hence, it can be O(n) in the worst case).

Anyhow, to find the nearest neighbor in log(n) is possible by a good data structure. You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7114541/3768871) to know more.

Comment: So, what can be said about the time complexity of this algorithm used in this method ?

Comment: @ninjawarrior  it can be O(n) in the worst case